# Any free Ajax poll script?

Tags: php, ajax, search

Do you guys know any free PHP Ajax poll script with an admin panel? I can't find one and I have googled for ages.

Comment: did you try searching for it on http://hotscripts.com?

Comment: yes there was one that i wanted there but the link was dead

Comment: And the other ones have watermarks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this simple AJAX poll script.
No it doesn't have admin panel. 
I think it's rare to find one with an admin panel, maybe I should make one.

http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=ajax-poller